# What is the distinction in indent behavior after a function and after a condition

Tags: emacs

My auto-indenting feature is treating the beginning of functions differently than the beginning of control statements.  I did not know that it could detect the difference.  What are the config options that determine the formatting behavior when these environments have been detected?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration for auto-indent depends on the major mode in use; try `C-h m` to see the doucmentation for the current buffer's major mode.